# Spring MVC interceptor vs Sitemesh

Tags: spring-mvc, sitemesh, thymeleaf

In a Spring MVC application using Sitemesh to decorate my views, I want to inject into every  `Model` a security attribute called **sec** of type `WebSecurityExpressionRoot`.

This way I could call hasAnyRole(), hasAuthority()... in all my views so administrators would be presented extra stuff by the underlying templating engine ([Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) BTW).

A custom `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` with an overridden postHandle(...) seems to be Spring MVC's way of accomplishing this, but it seems that my master Sitemesh decorator is kind of stealing my security attribute, because whenever I try to reference in some views it is null.

BUT only the views rendered after one of my controllers are affected, the ones 
mapped with `mvc:view-controller` do have the **sec** attribute.

I'm considering writing a `Filter` to stash **sec** into the current `HttpServletRequest` to solve this issue but I'm maybe missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `mvc:view-controller` views/path are hitting the interceptor?

Also, I don't know about Thymeleaf, but using JSPs (eg, `JstlView`) makes Spring MVC copy Model into Request attributes (for purposes of rendering the view) -- the fact that Sitemesh also gets the values via request attributes is, I think, a consequence.